# Rails DateHelper usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, date, coding-style

I'm new to Rails so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I have view and I want to display the time ago using (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words). Do I use this in my view or my controller?

Comment: This is Action View Helper so you can directly use the Helper in view. If you want to access this in Controllers then you may have to use something like http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/09/use-view-helper-methods-in-rails-3-controller/( I have not tried this)

Comment: Do I need to declare the Action View Helper anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Helper directly in your view. You don't need to declare ActionView anywhere, just place it in your view like this `<%= time_ago_in_words(10.minutes) %>`, replacing the `10.minutes` with whatever suits your particular use case.

The parameter (10.minutes) is therefore the 'from' and the 'to' is implied and not a parameter as it is fixed to `Time.now`.